# how to create a lzma file in python

Tags: python, compression, lzma

how to create a lzma file in python and add files

Comment: LZMA is a compression method, not a file archive format, so one cannot add files to a .lzma file. A typical example is that one creates a .tar archive of the input files and then compresses the archive using the LZMA method.

Answer (score 7):

Use [PyLZMA](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/projects/pylzma/).

1st result for Google: `python lzma`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, as of Python 3.3, there is an [lzma](http://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma) module in the standard library.

For earlier Pythons, [PyLZMA](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylzma) (as mentioned by @mcandre) is probably still your best bet.